# What's a good OS to put on an old laptop with 1.2Ghz Celeron and 256mb of RAM?

Tags: operating-systems, requirements

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What is the lightest-weight Linux distribution?](https://superuser.com/questions/38919/what-is-the-lightest-weight-linux-distribution)

I just thought I would see what people thought.  I can put XP SP3 on it, and it will run ok - but if there's a linux distro that would run better then I'm all for it.  I tried Xubuntu but XP actually runs better, so it would need to be something lighter weight than that!

Comment: See http://superuser.com/questions/38919/what-is-the-lightest-weight-linux-distribution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Any one of these [10 of lightweight Linux distributions](http://lightlinux.blogspot.com/2008/06/top-10-of-lightweight-linux_24.html) should do.

My suggestion is that you try a couple with [Live CD's](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Live_cd) before you choose to install one on the computer.

Comment: Thanks!  I'm going to try Puppy Linux - looks like there are more than a few people who like it.

Answer (score 0):

Windows 2000 :-) but seriously... Check out [Damn Small Linux](http://www.damnsmalllinux.org/), it'll run like a monster on that machine.

If you still have Xubuntu installed, first try installing and switching to [LXDE](http://lxde.org/). It is very lightweight and quite easy to use.

Answer (score 0):

[Puppy Linux](http://puppylinux.org)